# LineGraph.js:61 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5/29/22')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

this one is the screenshot of the error on console it shows the error which is occuring in three different places, and under this image i copied all the code which is causing the error so check out the code and see if anybody can help me out
this one is the screenshot of the error on console it shows the error which is occuring in three different places, and under this image i copied all the code which is causing the error so check out the code and see if anybody can help me out
[error message screenshot][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjjAC.png
```

Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import numeral from "numeral";

const options = {
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
  elements: {
    point: {
      radius: 0,
    },
  },
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  tooltips: {
    mode: "index",
    intersect: false,
    callbacks: {
      label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
        return numeral(tooltipItem.value).format("+0,0");
      },
    },
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        type: "time",
        time: {
          format: "DD/MM/YY",
          tooltipFormat: "ll",
        },
      },
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: function (value, index, values) {
            return numeral(value).format("0a");
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

const buildChartData = (data, casesType) => {
  let chartData = [];
  let lastDataPoint;
  for (let date in data.cases) {
    if (lastDataPoint) {
      let newDataPoint = {
        x: date,
        y: data[casesType][date] - lastDataPoint,
      };
      chartData.push(newDataPoint);
    }
    lastDataPoint = data[casesType][date];
  }
  return chartData;
};

function LineGraph({ casesType }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=120")
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          let chartData = buildChartData(data, casesType);
          setData(chartData);
          console.log(chartData);
          // buildChart(chartData);
        });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [casesType]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Graph</h1>
      {data?.length > 0 && (
        <Line
          data={{
            datasets: [
              {
                backgroundColor: "rgba(204, 16, 52, 0.5)",
                borderColor: "#CC1034",
                data: data,
              },
            ],
          }}
          options={options}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default LineGraph;
```

Comment: it's clear that the issue from the image is in this line `lastDataPoint = data[casesType][date];` you need to debug that carefully, the error is self-describing that you are trying to access something undefined, so in this line, `casesType` is undefined, try to trace the code and check what you are passing for this `casesType` prop and why is it undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your `caseType` variable in `buildChartData` function, most likely it's either `undefined` or `null` or some `error in a typo` which is causing the issue. from my guess, its value must either be `cases` or `deaths` or `recovered`.

Also, from what I noticed you have missed some registrations so add the following code at the beginning of your program.
to avoid `Error: "category" is not a registered scale`

```
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);
```